# Two Javascript functions one window.onload = Custom.init; and one window.onload = function() {

Tags: javascript, function

I'm using two functions one is from this site http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ and its using function call like this:

```
window.onload = Custom.init;
```

and after that I'm using another function call like this

```
window.onload = function() {...
```

The second one is killing first one!
How can I modifie or make different call on second one so they can work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {
    Custom.init();
    // ...
};
```

Comment: this one helped but when putted second one in first place like this `window.onload = function() {
     somefunction.init();
  Custom.init();
   
};`

Answer (score 4):

Use addEventListener/attachEvent.  You can use a library that abstracts this, like jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});
```

This can be run multiple times with different functions without issues.

Comment: If he'd have said jQuery, a jQuery answer might be appropriate.  But the question was specifically how to do it in JavaScript.  Loading a library just to abstract away `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` is a little overkill....

Comment: I think using the addEventListener/attachEvent is the way to go... of course, IE uses one nominclature, while WebKit and FF use another, so you have to account for both.  A library makes it so you don't have to worry about that, but spending an extra few minutes to account for both isn't too bad either.

Comment: @tkone, I specifically said he *can* do that, and I gave the underlying methods.  Most likely, other parts of his code could benefit from a library (it doesn't have to be jQuery).

Comment: @tkone, Using javascript without jQuery or other libraries nowadays is insane when there are lot of browsers with different functionalities. Thanks

Comment: @irfandar is it? I seem to be able to accomplish quite a bit without it. There are places where it is in appropriate to load it (eg bookmarklets) and if you don't know what it's doing for you behind the scenes you're sort of missing the point.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own function which calls them both.

```
window.onload = function(){
    Custom.init();
    function() { ... }
}
```

Comment: You certainly don't have to do it that way, and `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` is cleaner.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I'd actually argue it's not since then you have to do detection of the supported version and provide two different mechanisms for it.  While it might be more "appropriate" to do so, this is much quicker and cleaner since you're not worrying about interface support.

Comment: That's why I recommended jQuery or another library.

Answer (score 0):

My preference for this is:

```
loadFunctions = [];
window.onload = function() {var x; while(x = loadFunctions.shift()) x();};
```

Then, instead of setting `window.onload`, I do:

```
loadFunctions.push(function() {...});
```

Of course, I can do this because I'm not using external libraries which may interfere with `window.onload`.

EDIT: If you don't have control over one of them, you could do this:

```
var ool = window.onload;
window.onload = function() {
    if( ool) ool();
    // new code here
};
```

Comment: Kind of, but it's expandable ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Manually call `Custom.init` ?

```
window.onload = function() {
   Custom.init();
   //your stuff
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a nice little wrapper for all onLoad event handler?

```
window.onLoadHandlers = [];
window.onLoad = function() {
    while (window.onLoadHandlers.length) {
        window.onLoadHandlers.shift()();
    }
};
```

Then just push the two functions to that array:

```
window.onLoadHandlers.push( Custom.init );
window.onLoadHandlers.push( function() { ...
```

You may though consider using jQuery or any other library that provides a better solution for this.